# Can I use Excel addin functions in a Powerpoint addin?

Tags: vba, ms-office, office-addins

I have addins for Excel and Powerpoint which do similar things and have duplicated portions of their codebase. Would it be possible to have the duplicated code in one of the addins, and call it from the other?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012946/sharing-vba-modules-across-ms-office-applications) answer indicates my only option is to use VB6 to create a dll, but I'm wondering if there are any other options?

Comment: I don't think you can add it as a reference, you could use a hidden non-shown instance of either to use the addin that way, put some wrappers round publicly exposed to limit the code shown.

Comment: Thanks Nathan_Sav, how would I create a hidden non shown instance? How would I get a reference to the other addin, would it be like using late binding?

Comment: Ah I think I understand you, actually open an instance of PowerPoint containing the addin from Excel, and use it that way?

Comment: In one of my addins, in a standard module, I've a public wrapper like so `Public Function DatbaseController_ExecuteSQL(strSQL As String) As Boolean:clsDatabaseController.ExecuteSQL strSQL, , False:End Function`  this uses a class within the addin called `clsDatabaseController` and calls its function, ExecuteSQL with the argument strSQL.  This function is available then in the hidden excel object created.  From the non-excel side, we cannot create an instance of `clsDatabaseController`

Comment: I've created the public function in my addin, and added the addin to an Excel file, and opened that in Powerpoint and tried to execute the method both early and late bound, but I get "Object doesn't support this method"

Comment: it will be opening the addin to an excel object and calling like `appExcel.Run "function",arg1,arg2.........`

Comment: Thank you, I understand now

Comment: no probs, glad to help.