# Is there a way in ms access to share a public function the same way as in ms excel add-ins?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a function that I want to use with all my DBs, without adding the module containing the function to each DB.
In excel I can create an add-in containing the function that'll work with any excel file I open, is there something similar in access?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168674/using-a-centralized-vba-module-in-multiple-access-databases

Comment: It didn't work, also I don't want to add if for each database I have, I want something that always runs with any access instance.

Comment: Sounds like you need to create an Access addin see [here](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/access-add-ins.html)

Comment: This is a menu addin, it doesn't provide the functionality I want.
It seems access addins are different from excel addins.